# Upload to App Store, iTunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

i am using Xcode 8 GM version to upload my Application to the App Store. I've successfully passed the validation with no errors or warning, and successfully uploaded the project to the App Store (My release provisioning profiles seem to be fine). On iTunes connect i can see no build for my upload, i am using the same bundle, and the same version and fill all the required fields. The app status is prepare for submission. This is my first build for my project, and the problem is that no build appears neither under Activity nor under iOS App. Is it an issue with the iTunes connect or i do have to fix something.  I've tried the upload for several times each with a new build version.Screen shot are attached.

[image: No builds are shown]

Comment: Check your email for Apple Store team.

Comment: Add the keys to your Info.plist Apple Store Team asked in email , and give it a `String value`.Then upload it again. You can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432242/nsphotolibraryusagedescription-in-xcode8.