# NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in Xcode8

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight, ios10, xcode8

***Update***:
I attempt to add a String value to the `"NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription"` key.
[image]

And it works.My build version is now available on my TestFlight.

[image]
ps: **构建版本** means **Build Version**

But I want to know why Apple Store just let me add String value for `"NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription"` key rather than `"Camera Usage Description"` or `"Location When In Use Usage Description"`?
And how to localize the info.plist.

---

***Old***:
I've uploaded many build versions to iTunes Connect.But TestFlight shows none of these build versions.
Then I search this issue on stackoverflow. And I know this is caused by usage description. I add the **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription** in my Info.plist.
However, Apple Store team email and tell me that:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Family Health Tracker". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription** key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

They still tell me add **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription**

[image: This is my Info.plist]

Comment: Thanks Apple - I love re-archiving and re-uploading my entire application to put in one string. It even made me update the build number. Just put this on the iTunes Connect GUI where it should be

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App rejected due to missing usage descriptions (Xcode8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415895/app-rejected-due-to-missing-usage-descriptions-xcode8)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Localizing of `info.plist` file may be very unuseful, especially if you use many languages in your apps.
The simplest way for localizing `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`or `NSCameraUsageDescription` keys is to describe it in `InfoPlist.strings` file.

- Create new `*.strings` file with name `InfoPlist`;
- Press `Localize...` button in file inspector and choose the default language;
- Add new records in your new `InfoPlist.strings` file. For example
  in English:

> NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription = "Location usage description";
>
> NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription = "Photos usage description";
>
> NSCameraUsageDescription = "Camera usage description";

For more information [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html)

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" has value assigned before uploading the app to iTunesConnect.

[image]

Comment: I have it and yet when I uploaded the build I got an email from the App store team. So weird

Comment: what kind of value it should be there? and where is will be displayed for the user?

Comment: it's a string type value. And it will be displayed at the first time app asking for photo authorization.@Ashoor

Comment: Ashoor: the exact text displays to the user as the smaller description that helps a user understand why your app is asking for permission. So, be polite, concise and professional. Include your app's name first, so perhaps something like: "MyGreatApp requires access to your Photos to allow you to add selected photos to a blog in the app."

Answer (score 4):

Simply add these lines to your info.plist file

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Library Access Warning</string> //For NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription issue.
```

Answer (score 2):

To localize the Info.plist:

- Click your `Info.plist`
- Show your `Utilities`, then click `File inspector`
- This is a button `Localize`, click it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with two applications, the solution shows you the itunnes connect via mail:
**info.plist** review your file and tries to add the following fields:

```
  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

  Bluetooth Sharing - NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription
```

each with a text explaining the reason for its use.
You can check here the permissions that now requires **iOS 10** in its **info.plist** here:
https://blog.xamarin.com/new-ios-10-privacy-permission-settings/

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it work for us,

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
```

For more details please refer [Best Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519960/4527240)

Hope this will help for some .

Answer (score 0):

The `missing keys` are related to some APIs requiring some usage descriptions defined in the .plist keys. Before adding any keys if you know that your app doesn't make any specific usage I will recommend you take a look at this official [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1937/_index.html) from Apple to identity faulty API classes. As an example I simply have a comment out on a line containing `UIImagePickerController`. This was enough to get the binary rejection from Apple; while I didn't access to the user photo library. Once you validated this step you can go ahead with other solutions mentioned here.