# I can't upload App build on iTunes Connect with Xcode 8.

Tags: upload, app-store-connect, xcode8

I can't upload App build on iTunes Connect with Xcode 8. More exactly I can and Organiser show my success message about it but on iTunes Connect not appearing any new builds. During build are processing I can see it but when processing end build just disappear from list of builds. I try upload 5 builds already and result is same. Uploading worked fine with Xcode 7. I no have idea what can I do now and my customer is very angry because I can't show him my work. Please help.

Comment: looks like you are not alone. lot of other users are facing same issue. Write to apple to get it corrected. Have you tried uploading build using application loader? https://twitter.com/hashtag/itunesconnect?lang=en

Comment: I loading app with Organizer.

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432242/nsphotolibraryusagedescription-in-xcode8

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that if you are using Xcode 8 that you are using the beta version - which will **NOT** allow you to upload to the App store at all.