# New build disappears after uploading it to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode8

I'm trying to upload a build to iTunesConnect with Xcode 8. Xcode shows me that the uploading is successful. In Activity tab of iTunesConnect I see that my build is appears and it's marked as "processing...". But after a few minutes this build disappears and I cannot find it anywhere. I tried to upload it again by Xcode 8, but it says the build is already uploaded to iTunesConnect. So when I tried to upload build with increased version it says OK, but I still cannot see the build in iTunesConnect. I tried to upload with Application Loader, but there is the same issue.

Comment: Sometimes there are issues on App Store, probably it will work tomorrow ok.  Anyway you should do "validate" to build before upload to App Store

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to upload the build a 5 days ago and I still cannot do it.

Comment: @chudin26 please increase the build number don't change the version number and try to upload again.

Comment: I have the same issue, the build does not appear in itunes connect

Comment: I have same problem , any update on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I have the same issue, i have added 3 builds so far 2.0.2 / 2.0.3 / 2.0.4. All show as success while uploading but can't find them in Activity or TestFlight Tabs. Both tabs have 2.0.1 as the last build there.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Check your email. App Store review may send you a email for User Usage.
This may help you. [NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in Xcode8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432242/nsphotolibraryusagedescription-in-xcode8)

Comment: Adding NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription doesn't resolve my issue. I don't have an able to check email now, because the apple account is not mine. I can do it after 1-2 days.

Comment: I mean that your app maybe lack one or more UsageDescription in your info.plist.The email App sent to you will tell you detail.

Comment: I'm one week with this situation, the new build doesn't appear also after this solution, nothing to do, this is very frustrating..I've also send 2 email to apple contacts without receive any answers..

Comment: did  you set a string value , not nil

Comment: Hey Apple, some of us hate riddles, quit doing this sort of thing.

Comment: I also have same issue. I am not taking any privacy information from user. But still my build is disappearing from iTunes. Also i am not getting any mail from app. Nothing is happening, I’ve also tried to contact apple support but does not work. come on apple....

Comment: They send and email stating the reason after making the binary disappear. In our case, we were targeting the build to a version that somehow Apple cant support. From apple email : Invalid Bundle - Submitting asset catalogs targeting iOS 8.3 or iOS 8.4 is currently unsupported. You'll either need to change the deployment target back to iOS 8.2 (or lower), or move it forward to iOS 9.0 or later.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue. Build gone after a few minutes. No email, no error...

I finally *added a second user to my account*, with another apple ID. That user could then receive an email explaining that some privacy settings (bluetooth usage) were missing...

Apple I just hate you as a developer. Bad tools, bad architecture, bad support.

Comment: I upvoted this out of frustration, agreeing with all you had to say about how bad the Apple experience can be.  But then I found that I did have some emails that I hadn't been reading, because they look just like the ones where Apple warns you about things that don't matter.  But this time I had to set a bunch of the usage strings in Info.plist for things that my code doesn't use.  So, in the end your answer did point me at the solution, and the up vote was fully deserved, BOTH because it lead to the answer AND because there was yet more evidence to support the case for hating Apple.

Comment: In Apple's defence, their developer support is 1000 times better than Google's is.

Answer (score 10):

You have to wait like 5 - 20 mins and you will find the app in Activity tab (left side).

If you are in admin position for that developer account, you will receive an email about the state of the build you submitted.

Comment: I had all the privacy settings in place, but my build was missing. Finally found it under activity tab.

Comment: Yeah, when it moves from processing to active, there's a 5 minute delay, and an email is also sent out. But if you don't have access to the contact email, you'll miss any additional problems or this confirmation email.

Answer (score 9):

I also faced same issue. After adding missing privacy-sensitive key data usage in apps Info.plist the problem is fixed.

1. Check and add the missing keys in your Info.plist file. Refer the link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html for more info.
2. Some keys might be used by the 3rd party pods included in your application. Find them and include in your Info.plist file.(You can get them easily from App Store email sent to you)

3.Following are the keys which fixed my issue, add,NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription,NSCalendarsUsageDescription,NSContactsUsageDescription,NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription,NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue. Without access to email of that Itunes Connect account, it's almost impossible to detect that something is wrong (it seems, that apps not crashing anymore if privacy keys are missing, [as it described here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/)). I guess you know what device capabilities your app uses. So you can try to add privacy keys you needed to Info.plist (check "Privacy - ... Usage Description" keys [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html))

Comment: I added all of needed privacy usage descriptions, but it still doesn't work. Only one solution I found is the uploading the build by Xcode 7.3. But I cannot build my project because Xcode 7.3 doesn't support new Xcode 8 storyboard format. I should to convert my storyboards edited by Xcode 8 to old format, but this converting is not good. I got a bugs in layout..

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, and I sent a mail to App Store Developer Support.
They replied me today as follow:

> It can take up to 24 hours for a newly submitted build to process. If
>   your recently submitted build has been processing for more than 24
>   hours, we recommend submitting a new build with a higher build number
>   as this typically resolves the issue. If after submitting a new build,
>   you have a processing time of more than 24 hours, please respond to
>   this message with the following information: - App Name - Apple ID of
>   the App - Prerelease Version and Build number that is currently
>   processing - A screenshot illustrating the current build(s) processing
>   in the TestFlight section of iTunes Connect.

Give it a try!

*update:

I solve the issue after a add usage description (like photo, camera...) in plist.*

Answer (score 3):

With the help of Apple Support Staff, I found one more reason that can cause this problem.

If there are older versions of third party frameworks (in my case the culprit was GoogleMobileAds.framework), the app build will be removed after processing, without errors or warnings. If you encounter this problem, check and update all third party frameworks that are used i your app.

Comment: WOW! I have multiple 3rd party libraries and some of them I cannot update, they don't work on newer versions. This is a massive problem

Comment: So I figured out its not that you need to keep all 3rd parties libraries completely up to date, but to keep the iOS sdks the 3rd party libraries use up to date enough for the store requirements

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me also last week. Nothing changed with my old app, just want to release a new version with minor changes. I uploaded my IPA to server, after some processing, the build was disappeared from the Activity page. I also didn't received any email from Apple describing the error.

I opened a ticket to Apple at Friday. At Tuesday, suddenly all my builds finished processing and be available on the Activity page. I think some triggering was done by Apple. Then I sent my last build to review and they replied my ticket with saying that since my build was in queue for review, is there anything else they can help.

May be someone else can use this information and hope Apple will update their system so that we can see the errors on the web page if any, not wait for an email.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to submit the build to app store after adding all privacy keys required to be added in info.plist.Make sure to go through the list from below link to check services we are accessing in our app require privacy keys to be added for ios10 support https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

I was missing NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription privacy key in info.plist & after adding this key to info.plist I was able to upload to itunesconnect successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Got hit with same issue. Tried every possible steps including;
1. Incrementing build number
2. Adding required usage description
3. Tried both options: Xcode8 as well as application loader.
   Nothing worked in my case. Build was successfully validated and showing in "Activity" tab of itunesconnect showing as "Processing". once you refresh the itunesconnect portal, it got disappeared.

Now, what worked is : Once build shows as "Processing" in itunesconnect portal,just wait and do nothing in itunesconnect portal. DON'T refresh the all builds tab around 2-3 hours depending on your app size.(Seems no logic but this is the way it worked.)

After then, binary will be available for submitting in itunesconnect.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

1. Check your pods, if they have the last version (pod update). Apple will silently reject sometimes because of this.
2. Make sure all targets have the same devices checked (had a diff there)
3. Also compare your plist with the visual config in XCode. Sometimes there are discrepancies, XCode doesn't properly update the info.plist tags, if so, align both.
4. All the above with the privacy keys.

I can't believe that "silently reject/ remove"  is a thing for Apple, but well...

Answer (score 0):

Build disappeared. Wondered why, but did nothing. 12 hours later, was notified that it has completed processing and I was able to deploy it to TestFlight testers.

Thought perhaps it was because I accidentally uploaded an archive of my previous .ipa first via the Application Loader, rather than the newly exported one. But this may be just random circumstances. Either way, I did nothing, and it reappeared—albeit 12 hours later when often processing has been completing in about 20-30 minutes recently.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, but it was due to permission issue.

App need Audio Recording permission, which were missing in info.plist. Please check your info.plist and all required permission.

After that app is successfully submitted and displayed on iTuneConnets.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem. The app did send to TestFlight successfully `4 days ago`. But tester said, she can not see the newest released app in TestFlight app.

I log in iTunesConnect and verify the newest app have been ready 4 days ago. But my TestFlight app cannot see it. I refresh app list in TestFlight 2 ~ 3 times, and re-install app from TestFlight. Then the tester said she receive the notification email about newest app is ready.... And I can see the newest app finally.

I don't know what happen at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem. I tried with different builds but it failed, Finally i checked my plist it have permission key but no description. 
I was using addressbook framework to fetch contacts but later on move to CNContact, Key in plist without description was working fine but after adding CNContact App is removed from Activity view of itunes after uploading.

Please check every permission key have description or not, Apple can remove your app from Activity/Testflight when you upload.

Comment: I figured out that Apple sends email if the build has no Keys in plist

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was a missing BitCode flag.
I don't remember why I had disabled bitcode, but I have been successfully uploading with bitcode disabled for a month or so.

Suddenly the uploaded builds started disappearing shortly after they had begun processing, but when I enabled bitcode, the upload was again correctly recognized in the appstoreconnect console.

Now I finally get the mails of completed processing, and I can access the uploaded build as normal.

EDIT: The non-bitcode uploads did eventually appear after 4 days, while the one with bitcode took 30 min.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Cordova-based App build.

The problem seemed to be that the app was still using `UIWebView`. I was able to solve the problem by adding `<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />` to config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
<false/>
```

in my `Info.plist` but not in the `Info.plist` of some of my app extensions, and App Store connect was silently deleting the builds after processing. I made them all match and it worked. Lame that there's no error message!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that I had started preparing the release while the archive was being created.

I had uploaded v1.0.0 of my app, and it had passed app store review and was available for sale.

Based on user feedback, I made some very minor changes to the UI text ONLY and created v1.0.1. No changes to libraries, no new permissions etc. Imagine my surprise when I was not able to see the build after uploading.

I ended up resubmitting 5 times (build 7 to build 11). I even downgraded my version of xcode and retried. Nothing helped.

Then, I remembered that I had started creating a new release v1.0.1 in the App Store and had saved the new release information. My thought was that once the build was available, I would attach it and submit for review.

I could not find a way to delete the partially created release, so I changed the version in xcode to v1.0.2 and retried. And it worked.

I then changed the app store release version also to v1.0.2, associated the build and submitted for review.

Screenshots of the lost releases:
[image: still processing version]
[image: and now it is gone]
[image: only 1.0.2 works]

Comment: Update: I did not receive *any* emails except for the successfully uploaded version. The intermediate versions disappeared into `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Support will send an email to admin. Please check email you might have missing permissions in you info.plist file.
In my case i got an email in which apple store mention of two missing permissions. Thats why after processing is complete apple reject your app and its not available on testFlight any more.

**ITMS-00000:** Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required.

Answer (score 0):

Men the reason of it can be everyhing. In my case I added swift package locally and the "mistake" was `The bundle at ... does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.`
In short additional plist file contains an **extra** key - no key is missing.