# I'm deploy IOS app in iTunes app store but IOS app build not showing up in iTunes and iOS app activity “Processing”

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Hope you are doing well

I know there are a lot of questions about this already, And I followed all answers but I am fairly certain my question has not been answered yet.
I uploaded a build of my iOS app via Xcode  or Application Loader with validation , and that went well. I got to the a message of "Uploaded Successful", so I thought it was okay.

Then I went to check in iTunes Connect and I can see a build ( under "Activity") with activity status processing . I waited for an hour but after that its gone.
I given access whole privacy and library in info.plist
Now I have uploaded 20+ time but same thing happen and I didn't get any single warning, error and mail than how can find exact solution. i have attachment screen short so please check and suggest to how to resolve this.

Again I uploaded new version whatever you give instruction and i followed step by step so now i attachment shcreenshort with
1 App info -version and build 
[App Info image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7la9.png)

2 info-plist - version short string and build 
[Info-Plist image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fedbY.png)

3 archive - using new latest Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)
[Archive Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ofqI.png)

4 validation - validation message 
[Validation message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HElp9.png)

5 uploaded - uploaded successfully message 
[Uploaded message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLmPx.png)

6 iTunes version - app version and iTunes version are same.
[Itunes Version image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziUib.png)

7 activity status - activity status is processing and after few min its disappears 
[app Activity builds status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw24t.png)

Comment: you need to wait for couple of minutes.Check with after 10 minutes.

Comment: what does it mean? I waited for an hour but after that its gone... Gone == disappeared?

Comment: thanks for reply but i waited one week.

Comment: "I waited for an hour but after that its gone" its not gone its been processed go to the build section and select tha last build you've uploaded then you're ready to go.

Comment: @aaisataev yes processing disappeared. and i waited one week, every day i uploaded

Comment: @Krishnakushwaha look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567555/new-build-disappears-after-uploading-it-to-itunes-connect

Comment: @dreamBegin but  im not find any build there

Comment: @aaisataev yes i seen your link and there only talk about NSPrivacy and library and i told that i already added whole privacy and library

Comment: @dreamBegin please see this my build activity in this image URL https://imgur.com/a/gvMv9aN

Comment: There is something you're missing sir, Try to start from the scratch like the credential and all the necessary things there must something missing.

Comment: @dreamBegin yaa but i unable to understand what are missing. if i get any hint than i can understand i already contact to developer account but they are not give any response. now i really tired.

Comment: Which XCode version you were using when you started developing your project?

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal Version 9.3.1 (9E501)

Comment: Just try with Xcode 9.3.1 for uploading the build, once for a try.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal just now i again uploaded please see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS3ac.png

Comment: Ok @Krishnakushwaha, let us know if it appears for submit or again it goes disappeared.

Comment: again it goes disappeared.

Comment: The reason why app remove from the activity. it send mail to client's appleID mail account please check on that.

Comment: @HardikThakkar - But i didn't get any mail

Comment: Hey guys please help me, now i m very frustrate so again according your instruction i build new version and i changed question summary  so please check one time. i builded new version step by step and mentioned  screen short  here.

Comment: But as per my experience it must send mail on apple ID's email. and check each and every setting you made to upload application. Like certificate of production environment, create new version on app store for upload build etc... At last solution is you mail to apple support center and ask them to give you reason for the same issue.

Comment: @HardikThakkar i know that but seriously i didn't get any mail.

Comment: Yes but try to mail in support center they will help you in this case. Do one thing Archive build and export from that. and try to upload using **Appliaction loader** or that 9.4.1 xcode.

Comment: @HardikThakkar previously i told to i'm use both are application loader and xcode 9.4.1 but same thing happen

Answer (score 0):

From all the information I get from the comments I think there's a version/build difference between the builds you are uploading try to set the version 1.1 and build 1 for the app :-

[image]

**Update**

Looks like the issue is in your info.plist You need to add appropriate privacy messages string for the services you're using in the app for example for the Camera you have mentioned "Open camera permission", This doesn't specify why the app require to use the camera? the message should be something like "This app requires your permission to access Camera to capture property pictures for the services provided by the application." *(Message will be according to your app requirement)*.And you need to update all the privacy messages.

Comment: No Previously i sent only for sample  now i can sent recent deploy  see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC2fv.png

Comment: in previous screen shot you had the v1.1 now this screenshot having v1.0.

Comment: yaa i tried both are firstly i tried 1.1 but its doesn't work according to me i think if version is uploaded and publish than u cant decease version

Comment: if you have any doubt  than i can start version 2.1 and build version 1.0 . is that ok

Comment: Thats a sure thing that you cannot decrease the version as far as i know maybe you try with a new version if you say so keep in mind to create a version at iTunesConnect before uploading with that version.

Comment: Hey guys please help me, now i m very frustrate so again according your instruction i build new version and i changed question summary so please check one time. i builded new version step by step and mentioned screen short here

Comment: ok i do that and i have one doubt , in my app im not using any thing like camera, media, photo, location etc. so its compulsory to mentioned all .

Comment: If you're not using any of the services please remove them from the plist.

Comment: but before one week i call to developer support so they told that its necessary . hey @dreamBegin if u feel free can we talk any screen share chat supported. i really tired. actually im new here so stack overflow required that You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk

Comment: No sir these keys are only used when you're using the particular services by requesting user to authorise the use of service, lets discuss [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179909/app-upload-issue)

Comment: please check your mail hangout and linkedin bcz i unable to chat here i dont have 20 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for response me. Finally i resolve this issues. 
firstly u need to two factor authentication.
After that use latest application loader.

open Xcode and click top Xcode ->open developer tool ->application loader

login with your developer mail id and password is two factor auth App specific password (two factor auth security options )

hope this is help to all.
thanks

Comment: previously i also used application loader but at time i  login with developer account credential. so u need to login mail id and two factor auth app specific passwords