# Itune connect rejects ios build with NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and warning with Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode8

I have my app in both app store and play store. Recently I've released a new build and upload to iTunesConnect successfully. iTunesConnect did not show the build but instead sending me a warning to my email:

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. 
>   The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key 
>   with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Though you are not required to fix the following issues, 
>   we wanted to make you aware of them:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app includes an API for Apple's 
>   Push Notification service, but the aps-environment entitlement is missing from the app's signature. 
>   To resolve this, make sure your App ID is enabled for push notification in the Provisioning Portal. 
>   Then, sign your app with a distribution provisioning profile that includes the aps-environment entitlement.
>
> This will create the correct signature, and you can resubmit your app. 
>   See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. 
>   If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. 
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>
> If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for 
>   information on removing the API.

As I understand **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription** causes this rejection. My current build use facebook invite plugin to invite user's facebook friend to use the app.

What string value should I put for this key?

In case of **Missing Push Notification Entitlement**  I already enable Push Notification in my apple developer page I also register dev/production keys to Firebase and able to receive push notifications to device normally. What I did new to push notification is to integrate a third party lib for local push. Can 
this Local push libs cause the warning above?

will I have to try to remove one by one to really see which one that cause the rejection?

Comment: Please search on both of these errors. Both have been covered several times.

Comment: [Missing Push Notification Entitlement](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+Missing+Push+Notification+Entitlement) and  [NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription+must+contain)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Push Notification Entitlement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement)

Comment: @thekbb NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription is causing the rejection. "Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them" is for Missing Push notification Entitlement.

Comment: yeah... both issues have many many answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in Xcode8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432242/nsphotolibraryusagedescription-in-xcode8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App rejected because of "Missing Push Notification Entitlement"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719182/app-rejected-because-of-missing-push-notification-entitlement)

Answer (score 1):

Your bundle reject because your App Store Distribution profile for does seems to have push notification entitlement.

Please make sure your apple ID has push notification enabled in production side as in image.

[image]

Comment: I receive push notification without any problem with Xcode prior to 8.  Sure I have this push notification enable and register the provision key with firebase.