# Can somebody provide me solution for apple app store

Tags: ios, itunes, info.plist, itunes-store, itunes-app

I received this message from the App Store Team:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   "App Name here" 1.11 (11). Please correct the following
>   issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
>   references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
>   Info.plist file should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key
>   with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely
>   why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted
>   to the App Store that access user data are required to include a
>   purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may
>   reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not
>   use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact
>   the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version
>   of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
>   (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

How can I fix the described issue?

Comment: You should open info.plist and add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with description why you ask for this permission. This text will appear to user when your app will request this permission.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in Xcode8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432242/nsphotolibraryusagedescription-in-xcode8)

Answer (score 0):

Basically `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` this key is used by Apple to show when your app is trying to access Photo Library first time. That time Apple will ask the user whether they want your app to access Photo Library. Popup will look like.

[image: this]

[image: Info.plist]

I hope I have cleared your question.